# Game center "Done" button doesn't work

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, game-center, gamekit

I am showing a Game Center Leaderboard but after it appears I can't close it—the "Done" button doesn't work.

Here is my code for RootViewController.m:

```
-(void) showLeaderboard {
    GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardVC [GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    if (leaderboardVC != nil) {
        [leaderboardVC setDelegate: self];
        [leaderboardVC setCategory: kLeaderboardID];
        [leaderboardVC setTimeScope: GKLeaderboardTimeScopeWeek];
        [self presentModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
    }
}

-(void)leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController 
{
    NSLog(@"Close leaderboard");
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

What's also strange is that I never see "Close leaderboard" in the log.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate to the list of protocols that this class implements? (leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish is the only method in this protocol). Your code looks perfect so this is the only thing I can think of.

Comment: yep, i add it to the RootViewController.h. But, ther is one more little thing, [leaderboardVC setDelegate: self] has issue its says that class has no UINavigationControlerDelegate.